# javascript - Get first level child items with 'id' attribute

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. For a given 'id' I want to find all it's 1st level child 'id' values.
Consider the code snipper below.

```js
function getFirstLevelChildIds(inpId) {
    var eleOut = document.getElementById('out');
    
    console.log("NODE");
    eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />NODE:'
    for(var node in inpId.childNodes) {
      console.log("node" + node);
      console.log("nodeType" + node.nodeType);
      eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />' + "node -> " + node;
    }

    console.log("CHILD");
    eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />CHILD:'
    for(var child in inpId.children) {
      console.log("child -> " + child);
      var eleOut = document.getElementById('out');
     eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />' + "child -> " + child;
    }

}

var rootID = document.getElementById("A");
getFirstLevelChildIds(rootID);
```

```html
<div id="A">New York
    <div id="B" >Jersey City
        <div id="E">Toronto</div>
        <div id="F">Boston</div>
    </div>
    <div id="C">Durango
        <div id="G">Atlanta</div>
        <div id="H">Milwaukee</div>
        <div id="I">Miami</div>
    </div>
    <div id="D">Greenville
        <div id="J">Madison</div>
        <div id="K">Washington</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Here, the children of A are B,C,D
and children of B are E,F

I tried using both childNodes and children calls and didn't work, plus the nodeType is undefined

Can someone please help fix this, using only javascript code (no jQuery)

Thanks,
-Sri

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#id > div[id]')

Comment: You completely misunderstood `for...in`. It's not like `for...of`. See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

Answer (score 1):

[The JavaScript `for .. in ..` statement iterates over the property *names* on the given object, not the values of those properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

You can use those names to get the values; for example,

```
for (var i in inpId.childNodes) {
  var node = inpId.childNodes[i];
  console.log("node" + node);
  console.log("nodeType" + node.nodeType);
  eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />' + "node -> " + node;
}
```

However! Note that `childNodes` is actually a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an Array, and thus has somewhat unexpected behavior when using `for .. in ..`.

I strongly recommend you instead use a more traditional for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inpId.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var node = inpId.childNodes[i];
  console.log("node" + node);
  console.log("nodeType" + node.nodeType);
  eleOut.innerHTML += '<br />' + "node -> " + node;
}
```

Comment: "*I strongly recommend you instead use a more traditional for loop*". Yes, absolutely. Could also use `[].forEach.call(inpId.childNodes, ...)`.

Comment: You _could_, but it's a bit of a hack

Comment: Not really, Array methods (such as [*forEach*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach)) are generic, so they're intended to be used on other types of object. It's a little risky passing a host object to a built–in function as *this*, but only IE 8 and lower care about that and for them, *forEach* needs a polyfill anyway so issue avoided. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "id" just

```
for (var i=0; i < node.children.length;i++) {
  var child=node.children[i]
  console.log(child.id)
}
```

also don't use the for in loop ... unless you know what your doing, because with this loop you also get propertys like "length" of the children array.
for in loop goes with a hasOwnProperty
(google for it)

Also, best way to learn and debug Javascript and Dom is to use DevTools.
I like the one Chrome offers, the most ...